# How do you parallelize accumulator and save it as text file in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, rdd, accumulator

I have pattern Accumulator that i want to parralize, how to i do this?

```
val patternsAcc = sc.collectionAccumulator[List[Patern]]("Paterns Accumulator")
...
...
//can't parallelize
val result = sc.parallelize(patternsAcc.value)
//save to file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `patternsAcc.value` is `java.util.List[List[Patern]]`, and is not accepted by the `sc.parrallelize()` method.

Simply `import scala.collection.JavaConversions._`, and your code should work because of  scala's implicit conversions.